# Efficient collection maintenance in a multi-threaded WCF service

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, synchronization

We have a simple WCF service that is tagged with InstanceContextMode = Single and ConcurrencyMode = Multiple. For methods  that return Lists, rather than going out to our database and filling the list when the call is made, we simply return a local copy of the list.  The list is maintained by a background thread that goes out to our database every 24 hours and repopulates the list. We handle the concurrency issues by locking on an object in 2 places: inside the method returning the collection, and inside the method filling the collection.

My question is, how can we make this more efficient. Currently, we have a bottleneck in out service method "GetCustomers" that the client will call:

```
public List<ZGpCustomer> GetCustomers()
{
    List<ZGpCustomer> customerListCopy = new List<ZGpCustomer>();
    lock (_customerLock)
    {
        customerListCopy = new List<ZGpCustomer>(_customers);
    }

    return customerListCopy;
}
```

Since "_customers" is being filled only every 24 hours, it seems like we should only every need to lock inside the GetCustomers method ONLY when we're modifying the collection. The way it is currently set up, if 1000 requests come in at the same time, we're effectively queuing the 1000 requests since only 1 thread will have access to that method at a time. This is rendering the multithreading aspect of the service somewhat useless, no?

Is there a best practice for this sort of pattern? Should I be using a more appropriate data collection to store my objects in? Would a "BlockingCollection" be a more suitable fit?

Comment: Without any evidence: You could have a look at the collections in System.Collections.Concurrent which I guess will handle the thing faster than the lock: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There most certainly is a more efficient way of doing this. The trick is to keep the master reference to the collection immutable. That way you never have to synchronize access on the reader side. Only the writer side of things needs a lock. The reader side needs nothing which means the readers stay highly concurrent. The only thing you need to do is mark the `_customers` reference as volatile.

```
// Variable declaration
object lockobj = new object();
volatile List<ZGpCustomer> _customers = new List<ZGpCustomer>();

// Writer
lock (lockobj)
{
  // Create a temporary copy.
  var copy = new List<ZGpCustomer>(_customers);

  // Modify the copy here.
  copy.Add(whatever);
  copy.Remove(whatever);

  // Now swap out the references.
  _customers = copy;
}

// Reader
public List<ZGpCustomer> GetCustomers()
{
    return new List<ZGpCustomer>(_customers);
}
```

If you are willing to change the signature of `GetCustomers` slightly you could exploit the immutability of `_customers` and return a readonly wrapper.

```
// Reader
public IList<ZGpCustomer> GetCustomers()
{
    return _customers.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...Could you explain a little more about your second comment regarding returning a readonly copy of the customer list? What risks do I run *not* following your suggestion regarding the readonly copy?

Comment: I should have said *wrapper* instead of *copy* to drive home the point that an actual copy operation might not be needed in `GetCustomers` which would increase performance even more.

Comment: Ah ok, gotcha. Thanks again for the info. I've never looked much into the value of volatile, so I suppose it's time!

Comment: Be warned...`volatile` is a tricky keyword :) The trick I presented here is definitely an advanced one.

Comment: Not sure if I should put submit this as a separate question or not, but it's still related to your answer above. I switched my dev code over to your suggestion and really don't see an increase in response time when I hit the service with a bunch of requests. I send 40 calls to GetCustomers in parallel from a console app, they're all sent right away but the responses seem to trickle in at the same speed as before I made the changes. The service is hosted in IIS, so I'm not sure if this is an IIS setting I need to change or a service config I need to change.

Comment: @Ryan: Not sure. It does suggest that contention was not the bottleneck afterall doesn't it? I'm not really an expert in highly scalable webservices so probably not a good person to ask.